# Laravel 9 - Выдаёт ошибку Undefined variable $reservations

Tags: php, laravel

Есть форма, при заполнении и отправки должно приходить на почту форма заполненых полей!

Но выдаёт ошибку

```
Undefined variable $reservations
```

всё перепробовал, но решения так и не нашёл.

Вот код в шаблоне письма

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <h3>Passenger information</h3>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>Имя:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Телефон:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->phone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>Repeat email:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->email_repeat}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Это код в контроллере

```
public function StoreReservation(Request $request) {
    Reservation::insert([
        'name' => $request -> name,
        'phone' => $request -> tel,
        'email' => $request -> email,
        'email_repeat' => $request -> email_repeat,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);


    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Your Reservation Submited Seccessfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    $to_name = 'Reservation';
    $to_email = 'mail@gmail.com';
    $reservations = array("name"=>"reservationa2", "body"=>"test mail");
    Mail::send('mail', $reservations, function ($message) use ($to_email) {
        $message->from("mail@gmail.com", 'username');
        $message->to($to_email)->subject('laravel reservation');
    });

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);

}
```

Comment: см ответ. Если возникнут вопросы - пишите под ответом. Если все ок, то поставьте галочку слева от ответа. Справка: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Получилось что? или ответ не подошел?..

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка, абсолютно верная - шаблон действительно не видит данную переменную, потому что вы её неправильно передали.

Во втором параметре передаётся не одна переменная, а ассоциативный массив в котором

- ключами будут названия переменных, которые будут доступны в шаблоне,
- а в значениях - их значения соответственно

Названия переменных в контроллере могут отличаться, от соответствующих переменных в шаблоне. Их названия передаются в ключах, после чего перед рендером шаблона письма вызывается функция `extract()` в которую передается тот самый массив, и данная функция извлекает значения в переменные с названиями, указанными в ключах.

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php

Другими словами вам нужно было передавать
не `$reservations`, 
а `['reservations' => $reservations]`

**Попробуйте так:**

```php
// создаем переменную, описывающий контекст письма
// содержащую массив с переменными, доступными в шаблоне
$params = [
    'reservations' => $reservations    
];

// передаем их вторым параметром.
Mail::send('mail', $params, function ($message) use ($to_email) {
    $message->from("mail@gmail.com", 'username');
    $message->to($to_email)->subject('laravel reservation');
});
```

**Подробнее в документации:**

https://laravel.su/docs/5.0/mail

#### Это еще не конец

На этом все не закончится ибо у вас есть еще одна ошибка

Смотрим Шаблон:

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <h3>Passenger information</h3>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>Имя:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Телефон:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->phone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="green">
            <td>Repeat email:</td>
            <td>{{$reservations->email_repeat}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

А теперь смотрим переменную, которую вы передали

```
$reservations = array("name"=>"reservationa2", "body"=>"test mail");
```

Шаблон ожидает объект `Reservation`, а вы ему передаете массив `["name"=>"reservationa2", "body"=>"test mail"]`

И после того как он попадет в шаблон будет еще одна ошибка,

- потому что это будет не объект, а массив
- и потому что у него не будет нужных полей.

Вам стоит сохранить результат вставки в переменную

```
$reservation = Reservation::insert([
    'name' => $request -> name,
    'phone' => $request -> tel,
    'email' => $request -> email,
    'email_repeat' => $request -> email_repeat,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
]);
```

и уже его передавать в шаблон

#### Итого

```
public function StoreReservation(Request $request) {
    $reservation = Reservation::insert([
        'name' => $request -> name,
        'phone' => $request -> tel,
        'email' => $request -> email,
        'email_repeat' => $request -> email_repeat,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);


    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Your Reservation Submited Seccessfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    $to_name = 'Reservation';
    $to_email = 'mail@gmail.com';

    // создаем переменную, описывающий контекст письма
    // содержащую массив с переменными, доступными в шаблоне
    $params = [
        'reservations' => $reservation    
    ];

    // передаем их вторым параметром.
    Mail::send('mail', $params, function ($message) use ($to_email) {
        $message->from("mail@gmail.com", 'username');
        $message->to($to_email)->subject('laravel reservation');
    });

    return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
}
```